# Hover over image and add the product to cart

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to add two products into a cart by clicking over the icon when the mouse hovers over the image. How can I first select the image then hover over to click the cart?

My code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("logout-trigger")));
driver.findElement(By.id("search-trigger")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys("Shampoo");
driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
//Shampoos are displayed now i am going to get any of those and click on checkout 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='product-listing']/grid-view-directive/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/a/img")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='product-listing']/grid-view-directive/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/a"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

HTML code:

For Image

```
<img class="img-responsive " alt="pClarifying ..."
     ng-src="https://web-examplestaging.com/cdn/images/ecommerce/products/thumbnails/Shmpoo_BIG_FLAT.png"
     ng-image-appear="" no-loader="" responsive="" bg-color="#ffffff"
     style="opacity: 1; transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0s; animation: 0.7s ease-in-out 0s normal none 1 running zoomIn;"
     src="https://example.com/cdn/images/ecommerce/products/thumbnails/Shampoo_BIG_FLAT.png">
```

for icon

```
<a title="Add to cart" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-mouseover="showgridViewToggle($index+1)"
   ng-click="helperService.addToCart('grid_product',prod.productSizeId,$index+1,prod.itemsPerBox)">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag faa-shake animated"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: can you please share error stack which you are getting

Comment: After hover mouse, you should hold on a few seconds before clicking.